# Difference TfsAdmin-FieldMapping and TFSFieldMapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, mapping, ms-project

Can anyone tell me whats the difference between those tools and the used function (shown below).To my understanding it's like that, but I don't get what's the difference:

**TfsAdmin**

It downloads a mapping file from the TFS Collection for Microsoft Project Server field mappings and can be found here:

%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TfsAdmin.exe ProjectServer /DownloadFieldMappings /collection:'Collection' /filePath:'filePath'

**TFSFieldMapping**

It downloads the mapping file from the team project for Microsoft Project Server field mappings and can be found here:

%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\11.0\TFSFieldMapping.exe download /collection:'Collection' /TeamProject:'TeamProject' /mappingfile:'MappingFile'

So what is the difference? Does the TFSFieldMapping provide me a subset of the fieldmappings of the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple Team Projects then `TfsAdmin.exe` will bring down all of your Mappings, bear in mind different Team Projects can be running different Templates and so could have multiple different fields.

A collection won't have any field mappings, they are controlled per Team Project / Template.

If you only have one team project in your collection, or if you only want to connect MS Project to a single Team Project, you can just use `TFSFieldMapping.exe` to get the mappings for that single project

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So my assumption was correct that TfsAdmin.exe provides me all mapped fields while TFSFieldMapping.exe provides me only the team project related fields. Do I go right with my other assumption that if I update a team project with TFSFieldMapping.exe that the collection mapping file will also get updated?

Comment: there is no collection mapping, just N number of Team project mappings sitting under a collection. but yes the 'collection mapping file' will get updated because the collections sub Team Project was updated